# SonarQube Fails to Start When Upgrading to PostgreSQL10

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I upgraded from Sonarqube 6.7 to 7.8 successfully. When I upgrade my database version from Postgres 9.6.9 to 9.6.11 it works great.

I have attempted this upgrade multiple times on multiple version of SonarQube 7.x. I have tried upgrading to the latest version of Postgres 9 before going to 10.

Once I try upgrading my database to Postgres 10.6 Sonarqube no longer will start. The web logs say:

"Web server startup failed" "Failed to read content of table schema_migrations" "Error: relation "schema_migrations" does not exist" "o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint Hard stopping Process"